# How to reinstall Ubuntu From Terminal?

Tags: command-line, system-installation

Is there any way to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 straight from the terminal? My terminal works but I literally almost purged my entire operating system by accident (bad advice from a community member). The terminal runs on a black screen now but it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

What about :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If that does not work, what did you remove . Any links to other questions elsewhere ?

Comment: Multiple statements saying:

Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntuone-control-panel/ubuntu-control-panel-qt_4.0.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb. 

Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' 

I purged a lot of stuff, I honestly have no idea...

Comment: Do you have an internet connection ? Can you ping google? If not, perhaps best to simply re-install.

Comment: I would suggest `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` (maybe someone forgot that) Anyway; hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just try updating Ubuntu to keep all your stuff and fix the problem.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo sed -i 's/quantal/raring/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```